# Show some indication that comments are loading

Tags: feature-request, comments, ajax

Today I suddenly suffered from a very slow internet connection.

When clicking the "show more comments" link, nothing happened:

> [image]

I clicked once, twice, nothing happened at all, and I had no way to know something happens behind the scenes. Only after half a minute or so, the comments (one comment in this case) were loaded.

Can we please get some visual indication that the click "worked" and comments  are loading? e.g.

- Add animated GIF next to the link
- Disable the link while it's loading